# Can I use Ubuntu on my Asus X454L?

Tags: drivers, software-installation, web-development

System requirements for Ubuntu Desktop Edition

- 2 GHz dual core processor.
- 2 GiB RAM (system memory)
- 25 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
- VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution.
  . . . ..

My Laptop config:

- processor: 1.9GHz
- RAM: 4GB
- System Type: 64bit

Now the question is can I use Ubuntu on my laptop with this configuration?

Another question:
which version of Ubuntu should I use?
Ubuntu Deskop?
or
Ubuntu Core? If yes then which version?

(Currently I am using win10 pro. I am a web developer)

Comment: See: [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can! If your laptop runs Windows 10 pro without issues, it can definitely run Ubuntu. Another option is Ubuntu Mate (https://ubuntu-mate.org/). It's an official alternative to Ubuntu designed for low spec devices.

Also, Ubuntu Core is not particularly well suited for Desktop, so I recommend sticking with stable Desktop releases (https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/developers).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [making a bootable USB stick](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0) and trying Ubuntu out without installing it. If it is too slow then consider installing a low-spec Ubuntu flavor like [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.net/) or [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/). Different flavours only differ in desktop environment and default programs, but the core functionality is the same. The newest LTS version is 16.04.4 so I would recommend installing it.